# Get value between tags TD (python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to take values between td tags. I tried to write the code, but I think it can be improved, made more beautiful, please tell me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
invite_date = str()
url = 'http://reestr.nostroy.ru/reestr/clients/233/members/5801625'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
news = soup.find('table', class_='items table')
i = 0
for tr in news.find_all('tr'):
    if tr.find('td'):
        if i == 6:
            cols = tr.findAll('td')
            for t in cols:
                invite_date = t.text
        i += 1
print (invite_date)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting only `invite_date`. You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
invite_date = str()
url = 'http://reestr.nostroy.ru/reestr/clients/233/members/5801625'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
news = soup.find('table', class_='items table')
invite_date = news.find_all('tr')[7].td.text
print(invite_date)
```

Output will be:

```
21.05.2019
```